# RichFaces "edit" component missing "onkeyup" event

Tags: javascript, dom-events, richfaces, onkeyup

I have to check the String length in a RichFaces editor component on client side.
The editor component does not have any `onkeyup` event, so I don't know, how to start the JavaScript function each time, when pressing a key.
Thank you for any client-side solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is the `ondirty` event, fired every time the content is changed. ([docs](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/4.3.X/4.3.3.Final/vdldoc/rich/editor.html))

Comment: Thank you, it helped a lot. But now I have the next question: how can I pass the text content of the "edit" component to my javascript function? I tried the following: ondirty = "javascript:myfunction(this.value)",
but the value is empty in my alert(..)